# How to update a value in a column with existing value in SQLite?

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to update a table in SQLite android. I have a column called 'quantity' which stores qty of some items, say item1, item2 ...
Now when I purchase item1, I'd definitely want to 'add' the purchased qty to an existing qty of item1.
I searched the web but couldn't find a solution, hence asking this.

My simple code's below:

```
// This method is used to 'UPDATE' the table 'stock'.
    // This method will be used by two fragments,
    // 'sale' and 'purchase' fragments.
    public int updateData(String cigaretteName,int quantity, int cost, int totalCost) {
        // Accessing the database with writable functionality so it can be updated.
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        // Creating content values object to put the new values in existing rows with old values.
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(StockEntry.COLUMN_QUANTITY, (StockEntry.COLUMN_QUANTITY + quantity));
        contentValues.put(StockEntry.COLUMN_COST, cost);
        contentValues.put(StockEntry.COLUMN_TOTAL_COST, totalCost);

        // Which row to update, based on the cigarette name.
        String selection = StockEntry.COLUMN_CIGARETTES_NAME + " LIKE ?";
        String[] selectionArgs = {cigaretteName};

        // Updating the table with the new values and then returning the number of rows affected.
        return db.update(StockEntry.TABLE_NAME, contentValues, selection, selectionArgs);
    }
```

This isn't working at all, now it doesn't even update the column/row.

```
contentValues.put(StockEntry.COLUMN_QUANTITY, (StockEntry.COLUMN_QUANTITY + quantity));
```

Do help guys!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest simple approach to overcome these kind of SQLite related issues.

1. Use **SQLite Manager** which is plugin for FireFox browser
2. Download from https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/
3. Create your dummy database there
4. Perform your CRUD operations here
5. Once everything working fine in **SQLite Manager** then use same query inside your project.

Above way will save your development time as well as testing.

Comment: Thanks @Nikhil Lotke, I'll definitely try that since I'm creating an app, which entirely depends on database.

Comment: I did what you suggested and ran Update statement in Sqlite manager n everything worked fine. But don't know what happened in java. Do you have a solution?????

Comment: OK, can you show me how you added query in your code?

Comment: Hi Nikhi it's Arpit here. R u talking about Sqlite manager?? If yes then it's `UPDATE stock SET quantity = quantity + new value, cost = value, total_cost = value WHERE cigarette_name = "Pine";` n if you are talking about running this into Java, then it's right above in my question.

Comment: in that case use below code in java code 'SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("UPDATE stock SET quantity = quantity + new value, cost = value, total_cost = value WHERE cigarette_name = \"Pine\"");'

Comment: This is what I tried: my function in 'Purchase.Java', which sends the user's 
 input `database.updateData(cigaretteName, quantity);` and the method in 'DbHelper' `public void updateData(String cigaretteName,int quantity) {
            // Accessing the database with writable functionality so it can be updated.
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();db.execSQL("UPDATE stock SET " + StockEntry.COLUMN_QUANTITY + " = " + (StockEntry.COLUMN_QUANTITY + quantity) + " WHERE " + StockEntry.COLUMN_CIGARETTES_NAME + " LIKE '%" + cigaretteName + "%'");`

Comment: This is the error I'm getting `FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.famiddle.genius.businessmanager, PID: 20213
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: quantity1 (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE stock SET quantity = quantity1 WHERE cigarettes_name LIKE '%Pine%'`

Comment: So it is adding the integer the user (well, that's me) passes to the column name.`no such column quantity1` The name of the column is `quantity` and the integer I passed with the help of editText is `1`